# Do we need to commit Ballerina.toml and Dependencies.toml when pushing to Github?

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

For the ballerina services and restful services, Is it a must to commit Ballerina.toml and Dependencies.toml files when pushing to remote repositories like Github? What is the possible best practise when committing files to Github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ballerina.toml is required since this file identifies a directory as a Ballerina package. Committing the Dependencies.toml  is not mandatory but recommended since it acts as the lock file for dependency version. If the file is not committed, the compiler will always resolve to the latest version. Since the dependencies can be released with new major versions with backward-incompatible changes, not having the Dependencies.toml  can break the build.